# React: To put simple logic in Container or Presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a container component which passes an array of objects down to a presentational component to output.

In the presentational component, I need to display the count of a number of these objects that meet certain criteria. Is it best practice to perform the count in the container component and pass it down to the presentational component or is it OK to do this count in the presentational component.

ie:

```jsx
export class ResultsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  countSexyObjects(){
    const matching = this.props.allObjects.filter((obj)=>{
      return obj.sexy === true;
    });

    return matching.length
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <PresentationalComponent  allObjects={this.props.allObjects}
                                  numberOfSexyObjects={this.countSexyObjects()} />
    );
  }
}


let PresentationalComponent = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      There are {props.numberOfSexyObjects} sexy objects
    </div>
  );
};
```

OR

```jsx
export class ResultsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <PresentationalComponent allObjects={this.props.allObjects} />
    );
  }
}


let PresentationalComponent = (props) => {

  const countSexyObjects = () => {
    const matching = this.props.allObjects.filter((obj)=>{
          return obj.sexy === true;
        });

    return matching.length
  };

  return (
    <div>
      There are {countSexyObjects()} sexy objects
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally state is considered an evil in React. I understand that React is built upon the concept of state but less state is more preferred, which means try to structure the code with mostly functions that are pure in nature.

IMHO in your first example is more correct. The `ResultsPage` is your Container Component(smart component) while the other is dumb. Dumb component doesn't manage state and just takes care of how the UI looks. You can put all the html, bootstrap logic in there.

The reason why this pattern is good is because lets say now you want to fetch the matching criteria from an XHR call, your code in the second case would be

```jsx
export class ResultsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  getSexyMatcher() {
    /* make ajax call here */
    return results;
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <PresentationalComponent allObjects={this.props.allObjects} sexyMatcher={getSexyMatcher()}/>
    );
  }
}


let PresentationalComponent = (props) => {

  const countSexyObjects = () => {
    const matching = this.props.allObjects.filter((obj)=>{
          return obj.sexy.match(props.sexyMatcher)
          // return obj.sexy === true;
        });

    return matching.length
  };

  return (
    <div>
      There are {countSexyObjects()} sexy objects
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice how you had to change two components for the same business logic? Much worse, what if someone else used that `PresentationalComponent` elsewhere in the codebase?
In the first case things are much simpler. Just have to add the ajax function in the smart component and pass down the results to the UI component.

Comment: Also this link might help - https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.2vdpxfulp

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first format for a few reasons:

- The smart component should a better idea of what a "SexyObject" is.  If its a field in the object, that's pretty simple and could be argued either way.  If it relies on a web service or some more complex logic to determine if it is sexy or not, you would never want that in the presentational layer.  Simple has a way of turning complex, so I'd use the structure that supports the complexity initially.
- Testing the code will be simpler with the logic in the smart component.  You can prime your component and then check the output variables from your fixed data set.
- If the criteria for "SexyObject" can change by the component, you would retain the ability to reuse your presentational component if you kept the selection logic separate.

Just my $0.02